# AngularJS - implementing orderBy in a table

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add filter in one of my columns that sorts by name.

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="setting in detailsExample.versionExample.settings | orderBy:'setting.name'">
        <td>{{setting.name}}</td>
        <td>{{setting.type}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Am I on the right track here using orderBy:'setting.name' ?

Comment: `orderBy:'name'` is what you would need. `setting` is implicit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name is enough in the filter. it is been well explained here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

so your answer will be

```
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="setting in detailsExample.versionExample.settings |    orderBy:'name'">
         <td>{{setting.name}}</td>
         <td>{{setting.type}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `'name'` only, also you could have 3rd option which would say `reverse` order of an array then you could set `orderBy:'name': true`

```
<tr ng-repeat="setting in detailsExample.versionExample.settings | orderBy:'name'">
```